# Menu prompt doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written an application in Python to work with strings, i made a menu prompt from which i can select an operation to do, i tested all the functions, they work well, except the menu and main functions, that when i enter my choice nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
import re
import os

def searchInFile(searched, file):
    try:
        f = open(file)
    except  IOError.strerror as e:
            print("Couldn't open the file: ", e)
    else:
        sea = re.compile(searched, re.IGNORECASE)
        for line in f:
            if re.search(sea, line):
                print(line, end='')

def validateWithPattern(string):
    patt = re.compile('([a-z0-9-_.])+@([a-z]+.)([a-z]{2,3})', re.IGNORECASE)
    if re.search(patt, string):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Not valid!")

def menu():
    print("|================MENU=================|\n", end='')
    print("|0- Exit the program                  |\n", end='')
    print("|1- Validate mail address             |\n", end='')
    print("|2- Search a string in a file         |\n", end='')
    print("|=====================================|\n", end='')
    b = input("->")
    return b

def main():
    b = 10
    while b != 0:
        b = menu()
        if b == 1:
                a = input('Enter you mail address: ')
                validateWithPattern(a)
        elif b == 2:
                a = input('Enter the file name: ')
                c = input('Enter the string: ')
                searchInFile(c, a)
        elif b == 0:
                os.system("PAUSE")
    else: print("Choice error")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
     main()
```

Comment: input() will return a string not an int, so `if b == 1` etc will always be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `b` variable you are returning from `menu` function is a string, not an integer, so you can't compare it with numbers (input is automatically saved as string). If you use `return int(b)` instead of `return b`, it will be ok.

Also, I think your `else: print("Choice error")` should be indented the same way your `if` and `elif` are, since you probably want to write "Choice error" only if `b` is not one of given choices. The way it is indented in your code will print "Choice error" after the `while` loop ends and it will not print that message if you input the value it can't recognize (for example 3).

Comment: Thank you!
I didn't notice that `input()` returns a string, i thought it formats the argument depending on its type.

Comment: @Youssef11 Python is dynamic language, it determines the type of a variable depending on it's value (you can have a string variable `s` and then say `s = 0` and it will suddenly become integer). `input()` returns string, so `b` is a string in that case, until you don't say otherwise.